Azure DevOps Server - queued tasks stuck in administration console
On DevOps Server 2022.0.1, with SQL Server 2019, I have tasks stuck as "queued" since days. For one project there are two CreateProject tasks shown as queued. "View Log" in the administration console shows "waiting for the job to start..." forever.
The problem started when importing Git-repositories, converted from TFVC with git-tfs. Probably just a coincidence.
As some of the unaffected projects are used in production, I cannot just re-install DevOps Server, and I haven't found any similar problems online.
Checked all the databases with the SQL Server installer, tried detaching and re-attaching collections - DetachCollection stays in "Queued" status as well.
Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Glad to see you in StackOverflow. Please cancel the existing jobs in the queue, create a new git repo directly, then try to build with this repo, is the build able to start? Please also try with a new self-hosted agent(or restart existing agent), is the build able to start? It's recommended to share pipeline definition, and more debug log for troubelshooting, do you have demands setting on yaml?

Whatever I do stays in "Queued" state, including a new build.
It's not the (on site) agents, in desparation I have removed and re-installed them.
The Administration Console shows admin tasks (like "detach") as queued forever, so I don't thing it's an agent problem, something is very stuck somewhere.

Have you cancelled the existing jobs in the queue before you start a new build? and choose a new git repo source as suggested above? Detach collection will not work, try to restart the ADO server. Please follow the suggestion and share the result to avoid confusion, thanks.

I have cancelled all jobs and restarted the DevOps server.
Background: We are moving from TFS 2018 to DevOps Server 2022, all projects have been migrated. But, with not enough time to finish the job, most projects still use TFS for their repos. The one using DevOps doesn't do automated builds (yet),
When cancelling old queued jobs, I found months old (scheduled) ones that had never run.
It looks as if the DevOps installation never has done any build job. The Git migration might just be a coincedence as the problem mighty have been there much longer. No-one noticed as no-one used it.

May i know if the agent status in online from agent pool? And if you upgrade to ADO server 2022, have you download the latest agent installation and register with this version to DevOps server?

The agent is online, and it's the latest agent available (2.217.2).
With "createProject" shown as stuck in the admin console, it might not be an agent issue.

On my ADO server 2022, the agent version is 3.225.2, it appears your agent version is old, suggest to upgrade it for a check. If the issue persists, can exclude the agent issue then. BTW, if you download the latest, and it's still 2.217.2, could you double check if the server version? Is it ADO server 2022?

Wasn't aware that the agents are on Github! Installed agent 3.239.1, DevOps Server is 2022.0.1.
Cancelled test build job, started a new one, still stuck.

If so, you can try to install the ADO server patch, check if it fixes.

Done, product version is now 19.205.34309.3, it updated 11 jobs. But the same CreateProject task is still "Queued" and View Logs still "Waiting for the job to start..."

After double checking the ticket, looks i misunderstood before. It's createproject service job on console not build job. As re-attach the project collection the issue persists, what i think the issue comes from sql server. you could need to restore a database backup in this case. Do remember to backup your database before restore.

The SQL Server logs showed "Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM" for all the DevOps databases. I made (under Security/Logins) the user NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM a sysadmin, and mapped that user to my databases. All working now, Thanks for your brilliant help and suggestions!

Thanks for your update, and glad to know it's resolved! I add the reply below.

It's createproject service job on console not build job. As re-attach the project collection the issue persists, the issue could come from sql server.
From the SQL Server logs, it showed "Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM" for all the DevOps databases. Add the user NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM a sysadmin(under Security/Logins), and mapped that user to databases. It fixed the issue.
